# How to fix prepend_child on non object in html2pdf (codeigniter)?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, pdf

I'm trying to use HTML2PDF to print a PDF page that is created with HTML with all its CSS.

I used it inside an AJAX request, to have the print after clicking on a button.
On the controller I implemented it in this way:

```
$this->load->library('html2pdf');
$this->html2pdf->folder('assest__/pdfs/');
$this->html2pdf->filename('printpage.pdf');
$this->html2pdf->paper('a4', 'portrait');
$this->html2pdf->html($view);
$this->html2pdf->create('download');
```

But I'm getting this kind of error:

> ***Call to a member function `prepend_child()` on a non object***

This kind of function is used in `frame_tree.cls.php` file. Whenever I try to print the `$frame` to which I apply the function it doesn't seem to be empty or null.

Here is what logs `print_r($frame)`:

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Voting to close as this question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I edited the question, trying to be more precise on my issues

Answer (score 0):

I am using mpdf, with inline CSS for each, and my framework is CodeIgniter, here is what I do:

1. I prepared one HTML template that will contain the information I need,
2. I used cURL to read that template, because am passing the parameters to it to generate the output.
3. I passed the text to mpdf, and done.